# How to send friend request to an individual user in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this block of code, trying to send a friend request to the specified user listed when I click "Add Friend". Instead of adding just that specific user as a friend though, my button is adding every user listed as a friend. I know it's likely because the button is placed in a foreach loop, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas how to make it so only the targeted user is sent the friend request, that'd be great.

```
@if($users)
    @foreach($users as $user)
<li class="media m-b">
    <a class="media-left" href="#">
        <img
                class="media-object img-circle"
                src="{{$user->photo->path}}">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <strong>{{$user->name}}</strong>
        <div class="media-body-actions">
            <button type="submit" onclick="{{ Auth::user()->sendFriendRequestTo($user) }}"  class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-sm">
                <span class="icon icon-add-user"></span>Add Friend</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because this

```
{{ Auth::user()->sendFriendRequestTo($user) }}
```

is executing method sendFriendRequestTo() for every user, it won't wait until you click the button, you cannot do it this way

What you want to do is to change that button to link that will point to a controller that will execute that method.
If you want to do this asynchronously you need to use AJAX